# Android LVL returns the correct code for everything but LICENSED

Tags: android, google-play, licensing, android-lvl, developer-console

When testing Licensing on the developer Console; whenever I change the response to `NOT_LICENSED` or `NOT_MARKET_MANAGED` or `CANNOT_CONNECT` it all responds as intended with no issues; however, when I set it to `LICENSED` it responds with `NOT_LICENSED` all the time.

I am using Strict Policy.

Things I have tried:

- Fake-bought (Google does not really charge you) my App through a link to the Play Store.
- Manually installed the same APK uploaded to the Dev Console.

Any insight on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might there be a fraud protection acting to prevent you from doing what seems like exploiting or faking a license? Have you been authenticated as the owner of the copy rights to the app in question (i.e. to assert that you are the only one who is allowed to do things like what you attempt)? You should also consider rephrasing your question so as to avoid the (in my opinion possible) impression of asking for help with license fraud.

Comment: Hello @Yunnosch thank for the suggestion, but I think the whole point of the licensing response testing is to test all possible responses and how your app manages it. I also think you might be onto something about me using a different email address than the one for dev, but I assumed all testers on the list would work the same way. I will test using the dev address. Thank you.

Comment: You might still want to explain a little about being the actual owner of the app, just for the impression of the question. Otherwise, if you find a solution (maybe based on my comment) create an answer. That would make everything perfectly clear. It also might make this an interesting and useful Q/A pair. Let me know if my comment was practically the answer, I will be happy to make it an actual answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch it did not work even with the developer account, I have reached to Dev Support since it is weird that only one response is not working. I will update this question on the matter once I have a resolution. Cheers

Comment: Seems the right way to go about this. Also notifying here might attract more comments or solution proposals of people seeing how it could be not a support issue. I will watch the progress.

Comment: @Yunnosch Ok I found the problem. It was caused by a mistake from my part. I had the License ID for my build flavors switched up and each of them were using the wrong one. I have now fixed that and the responses are working as intended. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds like not very impressive, but could be so easy an error to make that other people might benefit from you epxerience. I recommend making an answer and await voting.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:
OP considers possible that using the wrong E-Mail address for test buying could explain the problem.

OPs problem was solved differently (I assume OP will make an answer from that), but if you have the a similar problem check this, too.

(If this cannot be the reason let me know and explain, then I will delete this answer.)